# unable to add claim to id or access token based on attributes column of accounts table

Tags: curity

After many tests I can't figure out how to add claim to userinfo / id token / access token based on the SCIM 2.0 format for the attributes column inside accounts table.

- Curity 6.6.0
- Mysql configured as the default datasource also for user management
- Mysql attributes query configured in the datasource : **SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = :subject**
- User added through the User SCIM endpoint have their data inside the 'attributes' column of the accounts table (seems to be by design when the onyl one DS exists in Curity)
- family_name, given_name appears correctly in the id token as the connected user
- I'm using BFF Token handler SPA code (nodejs) with the overall flow validated

Step by step :

- Create a claim named 'user_type'
- select the default-account-manager associates with a claim provider
- in the 'select value' combo search and add userType (**all attributes of the SCIM 2.0 schema are referenced in the combo**)
- Add the claim to a custom scope & profile scope
- Configure the claim to be in the userInfo & Id Token & access token
- Commit
  --> No user_type field in any token or userInfo

I have tried with (return attributes.userType) and without any mapping, but no way...
The only working test is the one with a mock : return {userType: 'test'} or return 'test'.

It seems that the attributes query **SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = :subject** does'nt allow to use children fields of the attributes column.
Despite the fact that it seems to work correctly in https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-from-authenticated-subject/ subject attributes in authentication with code

```
function transform(attributes) {
  //Transform the attributes and return the appropriate value for the claim
     if(attributes.emails !== undefined 
        && attributes.emails.length > 0 
        && attributes.emails[0].value !== null) {
        //return {"email" : attributes.email};      
        return attributes.emails[0].value;
    }
  return null;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciate to point out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Since version 6.7.0 there is a new Token Designer which makes working with claims much simpler. You can read about it in these tutorials: https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-designer/ and https://curity.io/resources/learn/working-with-claims/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you got most of it right, but some details to tweak.
First, to use the attribute query, you can't use an Account Manager claims provider, that one uses the account query for the lookup and is not configurable. Instead, use the Data Source Claims Provider.
Second, the claim config can't query in multiple steps, so you'll need to transform your result.

In the picture below, I'm using a data source provider with your query, and putting the value from my attributes.timezone in the "email" claim.

[image: email claim transformation]

Note the `logger.warn`, it's useful to find out what you get back from the datasource.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Lost a lot of time figured it out, but so happy to solve it thanks to your answer in just 1 minute. Thanks again for all your work on Curity